Помогите разобраться с Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
Я хочу попытаться начать использовать di контейнеры для внедрения зависимостей.
Подскажите пожалуйста полный цикл работы с этим паттерном, библиотекой.
Например, у меня должно быть View у нее ViewModel, а у ViewModel есть несколько зависимостей - сервисы.
По идее как я нашел регистрируем View и ViewModel.
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
    services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
}

Потом получаем каждую сущность из провайдера в поля и как обычно суем друг в друга и показываем.
var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
var mainViewModel= serviceProvider.GetService<MainViewModel>();
mainWindow.DataContext = mainViewModel;
mainWindow.ShowDialog();

А как обстоят дела с сервисами для ViewModel, так же получать их в поля, а потом внедрять в конструктор??? Просто это должно быть по идее автоматическим делом.
Правильный ли код сверху с полями или же это делается как то по другому?

Внедрение зависимостей обычно происходит через конструктор, да, вам достаточно "зарезолвить" стартовую точку (что вы и сделали). Автоматически - вам контейнер внедрит все самостоятельно, вы только запросите нужный объект (public MainViewModel(SomeService service) { } - контейнер сам инициализирует и внедрит SomeService если тот был зарегистрирован в контейнере).

Понял, работает, спасибо)

@EvgeniyZ, небольшой вопросик, а если у меня много зарегистрированных зависимостей которые я должен получить в глубокой части программы, то как можно поступить? Нести в глубину классов провайдер, или же я только что намудрил сам провайдер зарегистрировать в контейнере как зависимость и он будет попадать куда нужно, правильно ли так или какой-то другой нужен механизм?

Почитайте про IoC - Inversion of Control (инверсия управления) и все сразу встанет на свои места.

Я почекал, короче провайдер является частью Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection и поэтому не надо его регистрировать в контейнере, достаточно просто указать в аргументах где требуется провайдер он его сам засунет)

Я вам ведь сказал про IoC. У вас не должно быть вложенности, у вас должны быть самостоятельные классы, которые легко внедрить в любое место проекта. Также у вас не должно быть new(). Ну и да, использование провайдера не очень хорошая идея.

У вас всё наоборот. Окно не должно быть синглтоном, как любое View. Время жизни View компонент контролирует WPF, а не вы. А вот вьюмодель наоборот - синглтон. Вы же разницу понимаете?
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
    services.AddTransient<MainWindow>();
}

Далее в окне в конструкторе
public MainWindow(MainViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = vm;
}

И теперь резолвим
var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
mainWindow.Show();

Готово, IoC контейнер сам создаст MainViewModel и сам её подсунет в конструктор окна.
Главное окно не надо вызывать через ShowDialog.
Если у вас дублируется окно, зайдите в App.xaml и уберите там StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml".

С другими сервисами точно так же. Регистрируете тип в контейнере, затем в конструкторе запрашиваете, и так по древовидной структуре контейнер построит вам все экземпляры.
На самом деле это я самое простое показал, и контейнер намного умнее и целую кучу штук умеет удобных. Документация.

А вот оно что понял, понял спасибо большое)
